# Firestore INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Got result for empty write pipeline

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, progressive-web-apps

I'm using Firebase-Firestore on Javascript (web) with a Progressive web app. I ran into this error:

`INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Got result for empty write pipeline`

Because Firebase runs asynchronously with XHR requests, it was difficult to determine the exact source of the error - it seemed like any `onSnapshot`, `set` or `update` was throwing this error for me.

And after that first error  came a flurry of other errors:

`INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: AsyncQueue is already failed: Error: FIRESTORE (5.3.0) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Got result for empty write pipeline`

I thought my operation was pretty normal - just using the API `set(), update() , onSnapshot()` functions when it happened.

It's not a mission critical error - the code runs fine, but I'm hit with a couple thousand errors when I open debug, so it's prohibitive in that regard.

For my PWA I was using a cache-first, web-reupdate model which returns `cachedResponse` but also `fetch()`es the response and caches the fetched response.

Anyone have any insights?

Comment: Additional information:
I'm using a progressive web app service worker.
When I turn the cache off and let it go to network only, the code works fine! I think the serviceWorker is interfering with the calls.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen edited - could you take another read through? I still can't really put down the exact lines of code because of the issue I noted above. Having solved this problem I think this is as close as I'll be getting to reproducibility, without giving the answer away in the question.

Comment: It's an internal assertion that failed, which should never happen. Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: If you're concerned about this because you're one of the firebase devs, it's alright, I've fixed it. The problem was that my PWA code was interfering with the CORS requests that firebase makes. Check out my answer below~

Comment: I'm concerned because it's an internal assertion that failed, which should never happen. But to get a better understanding of the cause, we need to see the full stack trace.

Comment: I've dropped a console log to you via chat - if you need anything else let me know!

Answer (score 0):

It was the PWA! Using the PWA, I was catching all `GET` requests, including Firebase's own `GET`'s. Filtering to ensure CORS requests don't return from cache fixed the problem.

To solve this, I added this code to my PWA:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
    if (event.request.method == "GET") {
      event.respondWith(
        (async function() {
          const cachedResponse = await cache.match(event.request, {
            ignoreSearch: true
          });
          // Returned the cached response if we have one, otherwise return the network response.
          if (cachedResponse && event.request.type!="cors") {
            //AVOID CORS FOR THINGS LIKE FIREBASE
            updateCache(event);
            return cachedResponse;
          } else return await updateCache(event);
        })()
      );
    } else {
      event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
    }
  });
```

If you're new to the PWA space, want to get a jump start to ANY PWA project, or want to just 'share notes', the repo with the full comprehensive PWA file is here: https://github.com/acenturyandabit/genUI/blob/master/Javascript/pwa.js

I've personally put a lot of time into this so I hope it helps :)

Comment: To add a bit more clarity, you shouldn't cache Firestore requests since they're all unique. And you definitely shouldn't use `ignoreSearch: true` since that means you'll ignore the querystring from the request when checking the cache and so every request we send will end up returning the same (wrong) data from your cache.  That is why you hit errors in the SDK.

Filtering out CORS requests is a sufficient solution, but it might be cleaner to only cache requests made to your origin (or other origins deemed safe), e.g. `if (event.request.url.startsWith(self.location.origin)) {`

Comment: I use ignoreSearc:true so that my front-end querystring based handler can know which files to load off my IndexedDB hahaha but yes well noted. Also there's a glitch with ignoreSearch that shifts the TTFB back up to 2s per request.